# Django-filter - I want to filter in different attributes with just one filter input

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter

Having the following model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=70)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=135)
    description = models.CharField(max_lenght=25000)
    ...
```

I want to use only one input to look by `name`, `short_description` and `description`.

So for example, if I have the following data:

object1:

```
name = "Amazing airplanes"
short_description = "This project wants to be ..."
description = "... ... ..."
```

object2:

```
name = "Testing potatoes as batteries"
short_description = "... ... ... "
description = "... this project ..."
```

object3:

```
name = "project creator"
short_description = "... ... ..."
description = "... ... ..."
```

And I filter in only one input of the filter by `project`, I must get the three objects as a result. (Also if one object have the same word in few attributes, it have to return me only one time that object)

What I have now is this:

```
class ProjectListFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    short_description = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    description = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name', 'short_description', 'description']
        queryset = Project.objects.all()
```

But this generates 3 inputs, and is what I'm trying to evade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a custom method for that, check [docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#customize-filtering-with-filter-method), your code should be something like this:

```
class ProjectListFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(method='my_filter')

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name', ]

    def my_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
         return queryset.filter(
             name__icontains=value
         ) | queryset.filter(
             short_description__icontains=value
         ) | queryset.filter(
             description__icontains=value
         )
```

Comment: Thank you very much! that's exactly what I wanted to do! I will recheck the docs to make myself clear about everything else.